# BeautifulSoup parse returning empty set

Tags: python, django, parsing, beautifulsoup, mechanize

(**updated code** right below here)

I have a class: `UrlData`, that generates a list of urls:

```
for url in urls:
    rawMechSiteInfo = mech.open(url)  #mechanize browse each url
    mech_response = mech.response()
    headers = mech_response.info()
    print "headers ", headers.getheader('Content-Type').encode('utf-8')
return
```

This line: `print "headers ", headers.getheader('Content-Type').encode('utf-8')`

**Is outputting nothing**

If I do a `print url_data.url_list()` in my `view`, its throwing:

```
<Scan.urldata.UrlData object at 0x103e73f50>
```

I'm simply trying to parse a a src of `html` markup like:

```
<div class="s">
   <div>
      <div class="f kv" style="white-space:nowrap">
         <cite class="vurls">www.somewebsite.com/</cite>‎
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The following **are working** in parsing the whole document:

```
HarvestLinks = 'h3',attrs={'class': 'r'}
```

or

```
HarvestLinks = BSObjOfUrl.find('cite','vurls')
```

it seems to work fine, but the last only returns a single result and there are *multiple*.

Thank you to those who have tried to help so far, any further ideas?

Comment: Try to search just for custom tags, to understand if they are  detected: HarvestLinks = BSObjOfUrl.find_all('cite')

Comment: It appears their not, if it was any non custom tag .e.g <p>, <a>, etc it would have been simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs, attrs is a poorly designed argument, and should be treated more like a **kwargs.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class indicates that you actually want to pass the class_ kwarg:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> src = """ <div class="s">
...    <div>
...       <div class="f kv" style="white-space:nowrap">
...          <cite class="vurls">www.somewebsite.com/</cite>\U+200E
...       </div>
...    </div>
... </div>
...
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(src)
>>> soup.find_all('cite')
[<cite class="vurls">www.somewebsite.com/</cite>]
>>> soup.find_all('cite', attr={'class': 'vurls'})
[]
>>> soup.find_all('cite', class_='vurls')
[<cite class="vurls">www.somewebsite.com/</cite>]
```

Comment: Please see updated code for the for() loop above.. This isnt outputting anything

Comment: _class is available only in BeautifulSoup >= 4.1.x

Comment: What version is being used? The current seems to be 4.3.2. The legacy 3.2.1 works perfectly fine with soup.findAll('cite', {'class': 'vurls'}). However, the use of find_all rather than findAll indicates 4.0? Can you upgrade your library?

Comment: I'm already using version 4 and I tried both examples, neither seem to work. As the commenter nickzam said, it think the attribute 'cite' is throwing it off

Comment: by using: class_='vurls' it outputs: [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []

Comment: by using: soup.find_all('cite') it outputs: [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []

Comment: I just noticed that I cut + pasted your input example and my terminal added "U+200E" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark). Maybe this is throwing it off?

Comment: After "I'm simply trying to parse:"

Comment: Don't worry so much about the output. It is strange it is just outputted empty sets, is it safe to say its looping properly?

Comment: And if you do `print BSObjOfUrl.cite` in function? `cite` string might be in different encoding so you are not finding it

Comment: where should this go @nickzam?

Comment: replace `HarvestLinks = BSObjOfUrl.find_all('cite', class_='vurls')
` with `print BSObjOfUrl.cite`

Comment: Please see updated code. Nothing is being outputted. Any ideas?

Comment: So `cite` string in your html and `cite` you are looking for in your code are 2 different strings. They have different encoding.

Comment: How can I fix this then? Is it possible?

Comment: Save html file somewhere and check hex representation of `cite` with hex editor. Then construct your string from hex characters, like that: `"7061756c".decode("hex")`. Other option is to copy `cite` directly from webpage source and paste it into your code.

Comment: How come HarvestLinks = BSObjOfUrl.find('cite','vurls') has worked all along then?

Comment: Also, I copied the values of 'cite' and 'vurls' from source page and pasted directly into: citeTag = link.find('cite',attrs={'class':'vurls'})   (e.g. my source code)  . I reloaded and it outputs: [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []

Comment: @CodeTalk. Which version of beautiful soup are you using, what platform are you running on, and where is your input coming from?

Comment: @JohnSpong The latest version, I ran pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade . Its been upgraded. I restarted my workspace too. I'm on OSX 10.8.5 and the values of cite and vurls are coming directly using AppleCmd+C from webpage into source

Comment: So does it work if instead of mech.response().read() you copy the source directly from the browser? Also, could you do: results = mech.response().read(); print results; BSObjOfUrl = BeautifulSoup(results) ?

Comment: I copied all output and pasted it in for mech.response().read() and it says some of the characters cannot be mapped as their MacRoman character encoding. Should I convert to UTF-8?

Comment: Use that instead of: BSObjOfUrl = BeautifulSoup(mech.response().read()) ?

Comment: I tried that and still get the [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []

Comment: Code is up to date above too. Any Thoughts @JohnSpong or @nickZam?

Comment: Everything works just fine on my machine. What is the output from "print results"?

Comment: I posted working code copied directly from my repl in my answer

Comment: Do you have somewhere on the top of your code `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of headers variable and report back, it seems that you still have wrong encoding:

```
def url_list(self):
    #setup mechanize
    ###
    ### Mechanize settings are here.
    ###

    for url in urls:
        rawMechSiteInfo = mech.open(url)  #mechanize browse each url
        mech_response = mech.response()
        headers = mech_response.info()
        print "headers ", headers.getheader('Content-Type')
        #results = unicode(mech_response.read()) 
        #BSObjOfUrl = BeautifulSoup(results)
        #HarvestLinks = BSObjOfUrl.find_all(u'cite', class_='vurls')
    #return HarvestLinks
    return
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I tried implementing this into my code (above is now updated), but it doesn't appear to be outputting the correct values and just `[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []`  instead (as we've seen before). Any further ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: Could you please provide link to source html or put somewhere it's source code. It seems that problem is with encoding, but I need to see a source to understand what's wrong.

Comment: By the way, your answer with: print "headers ", headers."Content-type"  is throwing an error of invalid syntax

Comment: Please see updated code I put and the error I'm receiving of: `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 209176: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: replace `headers.["Content-type"]` with `headers["Content-type"]` and report back `headers` value.

Comment: Getting error: closeable_response instance has no attribute '__getitem__' on this line: print headers["Content-type"]

Comment: `Headers` value is included above also

Comment: I updated my code, including some additional error logging on the string that cannot be encoded.

Comment: What is `headers` value?

Comment: headers <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x1027d20e0>

Comment: What python version do you use?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.1

Comment: I'm still seeing no output from your new code: print "headers ", headers.getheader('Content-Type')

Comment: Any ideas how to resolve this? I appears to be an issue with headers being populated, but your code print `"headers ", headers.getheader('Content-Type')`  isn't printing anything.

Comment: Updated my `for()` above

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `mechanize` before and I am using urllib2 and beautifulsoup4 all the time. 
I run into the encoding and decoding issues several times. Maybe some of my experience will help.

When you read text from the page, `elem.text`, the default is always unicode. Sometimes people have good luck print unicode directly to the screen and everything is fine. Sometimes, the console will not display the unicode correctly. Which indicates two things:

1. You have already ready the data in, the only problem is that you want to see it in the IDE (Eclipse, Pycharm, ..etc.) It will not work. You can write the unicode to your database or file without doing anything and sometimes it will be displayed correctly when you see the data outside your IDE.
2. If you want to see the text first  when you write your code(Who doesn't?) You can `print elem.text.encode('utf-8')` which I always have good luck with.

Comment: How do I incorporate your point #2 with my code? I would appreciate it.

Comment: @CodeTalk You mentioned you have problem with the print, maybe try `print "headers ", headers.getheader('Content-Type').encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: I tried this with my code above, its updated. Its not outputting anything

Comment: @CodeTalk um, what do you mean output nothing? It should at least print "headers ",... etc. right?

Comment: Its not outputting anything on the visible page

Comment: @CodeTalk Then it is a very interesting problem. The code before that line is wrong somehow. If you can send me an example link and the content you want, maybe I can be more helpful.

Comment: Please see the code above. I had the specific section I'm trying to parse above. See the html parsing section